# Unity MLAPI NetworkObject Sync with the wrong scale on Client

Tags: unity-game-engine, scale, multiplayer

my problem is, that when I spawn my Tiles as Host, the scale is right but when i Join as a Client,  the Tiles has the wrog scale. When I change the Scales of the Client Tiles during the Runtime, all my function does work. So what am I doing wrong?

**Here Spawn the Tiles when I start the Host**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MLAPI;
using MLAPI.Messaging;

public class TileMap : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public GameObject preFab;
    public GameObject parent;
    private float xMap = -95f;
    private float zMap = -95f;

public override void NetworkStart()
{
    if (!IsHost) { return; }
    for (int x = 1; x <= 20; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 20; z++)
        {

            GameObject TileOfMap = (GameObject)Instantiate(preFab, new Vector3(xMap, -0.4f, zMap), Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0), parent.transform);
            TileOfMap.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();
            zMap = zMap + 10;


        }
        xMap = xMap + 10;
        zMap = -95;
    }
    base.NetworkStart();
}
```

}

**This are the Prefab settings**

[Prefab settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nm3s.png)

**This is how it looks on Host side**
[Host side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfvCs.png)

**This is how it looks on Client side game view**
[Client side game view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbRdF.png)

**This is how it looks on Client side scene view**
[Client side scene view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzocG.png)

Comment: is your host built out as standalone player or is it a picture from in the editor like client? If your host _is_ built out as player, you might want to change editor game view to have a resolution that matches the resolution of your player builds. Right now you have it as "Free Aspect".

Comment: the host build is a standalone player. I changed the editor game view to the same resolution as the player build but the problem is the same. Even when i start two player builds i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the MLAPI documentation](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/components/networktransform/index.html):

> NetworkTransform does not sync the scale of the object.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't used NetworkTransform.